# Android Immersive mode and backwards compatability

Tags: android, api, android-4.4-kitkat, android-fullscreen

I want my app to be Immersive when appropriate and to mimic some of the functionality when the api is too low. Is this an appropriate way to do that? Is there a more efficient way?

```
private boolean apiTooLowForImmersive = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){

        apiTooLowForImmersive = true;

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus && !apiTooLowForImmersive ) {
        getWindow().getDecorView()
            .setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            );}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's the best way to do it (or well, it's the same system i use in my application)

Just a note, make `apiTooLowForImmersive` `static` and `public`

```
public static boolean apiTooLowForImmersive = false;
```

and give a value to it in a `static` block.

```
static { 
       apiTooLowForImmersive = 
               (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT); 
}
```

With this, you can use this field in every class and every time you need to know which code is safe to use.

Comment: So why use the static block? Why not just initialize it to that at creation? `public static boolean apiTLFI = (SDK_INT < KITKAT);`

Comment: Add the SuppressWarning ("NewApi"); it's an warning which reports you if you use something not supported (but you don't need the warning since you already handle this case) And yes you could do that. It's just me.

Comment: Just stumbled over `@TargetApi()`. Whats the difference? Thanks a ton!

Comment: With TatgetAPI you suppress the warning like the other with the difference that if you use a feature more recent of TargetAPI you get the warning again. Anyway it's not a real error at all, keep it to be sure to remember to use backward code if needed